# newbie python - global function into other function

Tags: python-3.x

In my school project I have to make global "list of clients" function so i dont have to open my files everytime i need something from this file in other functions. Here it says that client_list is not defined:

```
global client_list

def clients():
    client_list = []
    with open("svi.txt","r") as f:
        every_part = ["username","password","name","lastname","role"]
        for r in f.readlines():
            dicct = {}
            bla = r.strip().split("|")
            count = 0
            for i in bla:
                dicct[every_part[count]] = i
                count += 1
            client_list.append(dicct)
def log(file_path,user,password,delimiter):
    for r in client_list:
        n = r.strip().split(delimiter)
        username = n[0]
        passwordd = n[1]
        role = n[4]
        while username == user and passwordd == password:
            if role == "buyer":
                return buyer_menu2()
            elif role == "manager":
                return menager_menu2()
            elif role == "seller":
                return seller_menu2() 
    return False
def login():
    x = False

    while x == False:
        user = input("Username: ")
        password = input("Password: ")
        x = log("svi.txt",user,password,"|")
        if x == False:
            print()
            print("Wrong username or password, please try again. ")
            print()
    print()
login()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "global function", you actually mean "global variable", the following should help:

```
client_list = []

def clients():
    global client_list
    client_list = []
    with open("svi.txt","r") as f:
        every_part = ["username","password","name","lastname","role"]
        for r in f.readlines():
            dicct = {}
            bla = r.strip().split("|")
            count = 0
            for i in bla:
                dicct[every_part[count]] = i
                count += 1
            client_list.append(dicct)
def log(file_path,user,password,delimiter):
    # No need to declare client_list as global for reading it
    for r in client_list:
        n = r.strip().split(delimiter)
        username = n[0]
        passwordd = n[1]
        role = n[4]
        while username == user and passwordd == password:
            if role == "buyer":
                return buyer_menu2()
            elif role == "manager":
                return menager_menu2()
            elif role == "seller":
                return seller_menu2() 
    return False
def login():
    x = False

    while x == False:
        user = input("Username: ")
        password = input("Password: ")
        x = log("svi.txt",user,password,"|")
        if x == False:
            print()
            print("Wrong username or password, please try again. ")
            print()
    print()
login()
```

So don't declare client_list as global at the top of your file, but rather in those functions where you want to change its content.

**Edit Based on Comment:**
Of course, you'd have to call `clients` at least once in your program to initially fill your client_list. This is not done my code because I just took yours and assumed you're doing it somewhere else already.

Comment: It still wouldn't work though.  `clients()` was never called.  `client_list` would remain empty.

Comment: That's true, I assumed that he's calling clients() somewhere else in code. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: hmm, im not sure where should I call it

Comment: Probably right before you call `login()`, at least if this piece of code is the whole program.

Comment: the thing is, this has 40 lines of code the whole program has about 1000 and more maybe, so ill try to find out, thanks anyway, this was helpful.

Comment: hey man, do I need this client_list = [] after global client_list or you jsut didnt modify it?

Comment: You don't need it, but it assures that in case the function `clients()` gets called multiple times, the clients_list is always correct.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4693385/4243650), the `global` keyword in Python is for mutating or defining global variables *in a local context*. You don't need it to declare global variables in an already global scope, so where you are writing `global client_list`, you can just define the variable itself by writing something like `client_list = []`

Where you *will* need the `global` keyword is in any function you intend to modify your global `client_list` variable. So, for example, if you intend for the `clients()` function to append to (or otherwise mutate) the global `client_list`, it should include a `global client_list` declaration.

```
def clients():
    global client_list
    with open("svi.txt","r") as f:
    <the rest of your function>
```